# Blank screen is coming on magento site

Tags: php, .htaccess, magento, magento-1.7, magento-1.8

I have downloaded my live site(magento) for some code changes and testing, and configured in my local machine. And i have configured db in my local and changed the required settings like '`web/unsecure/base_url`', '`web/secure/base_url`' to as per my local settings.

But i am getting white blank screen for front and admin sections. And i tried to inspect the errors i wrote in index.php file like this

```
ini_set('display_errors',1);
error_reporting(E_ALL);
ini_set('memory_limit', '256M');
```

Even though the errors are not displaying please help me what are the required changes i missed exactly?

Comment: Please check any Extension scripts are running or not. I think it should be script issue.

Comment: I have disabled the community and local modules for testing, still no response

Comment: Can you access admin panel ?

Comment: No, Admin panel also same blank page

Comment: then it is something related to magento app. If any issue regarding the url/htaccess, error should be thrown.

Answer (score 0):

Delete **var** folder within the magento.

check your `[your_magento]/app/etc/local.xml` database connection and search static url in folder and replace with `localhost/[your_magento]/.`
Check any **php** syntax related error.

Answer (score 0):

1. check whether all files have been downloaded by you or not.
2. check app/etc/local.xml for database connection
3. delete empty session and cache folders inside var
4. check for permissions ,give 777 permissions to var,media,app/etc folders for linux go to the your magento directory and run following commands :

   sudo chmod -R 777 app/etc

   sudo chmod -R 777 media

   sudo chmod -R 777 var
5. if still not worked,then check your .htaccess file whether there are any changes required or not